# Python subprocess stoud handling while other code is running

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, subprocess, python-multithreading

I want to build a python script that start a subprocess and launches a CLI command(the cli command can take hours to run), so I want the main python to continue, however deploy a watcher, that keeps track if the process is alive or dead and is should also fetch the stdout and extract single values of stdout, then store those values in a db. However the DB is not a problem right now.

Current code I use:

```py
def run_subprocess(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output and output.strip():
            print(output.strip())


    process.wait()

#full_command is a streamlink based command.
run_subprocess(full_command)
```

The current code is able to extract the stdout of the process and pastest it into the python terminal, which is for the beginning good, but later I need to have line line1, line2..., so I can extract the bandwith, speed and file size.
Also while python is in this loop obv. no other code executes, is there a way to extract stdout while continuing in the main ? Also my code never exits that loop even if the subprocess came to an "end". Also it never prints the latest line,  it prints a line off, so basically I cannot display the latest line.

Just to better visualize an IMG of the sample output and the data I want to extract.

Thanks for any help and or suggestions!

Comment: Use multi-threading. Run this code in one thread, while the other thread executes your mainline code.